# ReferenceError: filename is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, routes

when i execute */wgt/myfile.html* in the browser i get:

**ReferenceError: filename is not defined**

in my router file i have the following:

```
 app.get('/js/:filename',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public/js', filename));
 });
 app.get('/wgt/:filename',function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public/views/widgets', filename));
 });
```

i set the location of myfile.html inside *public/js* and i executed */js/myfile.html* and it worked, i don't get the reason of the error i get with *wgt/myfile.html*.

Am i missing a package or a require to have this working right? Any ideas of how i can solve this?

Comment: Well where is the variable `filename` declared?

Comment: @Pointy it's a parameter in the URL, no need to declare it.

Comment: That doesn't matter; it's not a JavaScript variable.

Comment: @Pointy why is it working with /js/...  withou any declaration ?

Comment: @Hosni Pointy is right. You have not declared `filename` as a variable whatsoever, hence the error. Forget about these odd conditions where it's "working" because it's not. If you are attempting to get the `:filename` from the URL like I assume you are, you must use `req.params.filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using express, you should use the [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) object to access URL parameters.

```
 app.get('/wgt/:filename',function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public/views/widgets', req.params.filename));
 });
```